# Impossible to fill in the same boxes checked in a check box in a form using FormArrayName

Tags: angular, angularfire, angular14

I manage to add data by filling in the form fields.

But when I want to modify the added values [image]

I manage to fill all the fields with the data of the selected item except for the check boxes checked at the time of insertion (the selected months or letters).[image] [image]

I also have the following error:

```
ERROR Error: NG01002: Must supply a value for form control at index: 0
```

Here is the link to the typescript component: https://github.com/hermann-dev-10/app-admin-num/blob/main/src/app/components/dialog/dialog.component.ts

Here is also the HTML code of the component in question : https://github.com/hermann-dev-10/app-admin-num/blob/main/src/app/components/dialog/dialog.component.html

I think the problem comes from the fact that I am using formArrayName, I don't really see how to solve this so that the relevant checkboxes are checked, depending on the workbook I want to update.

Would you know where the problem could come from?

I thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Using ".patchValue" I manage to fill in checkboxes but it doesn't select the right ones... instead of the "setValue"

Comment: I have found an example of what I would like to achieve approximately : https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/setvalue-patchvalue-in-formarray-angular/

Comment: So I manage to check the checkboxes using ".patchValue()" but it doesn't necessarily check the right boxes...